# if statement- inside each jquery part II

Tags: jquery

How do I create HTML on the fly, looping through strings, and lists. I've had answers to the single single string, in [if statement inside $.each, Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926573/if-statement-inside-each-jquery), but I believe this merits a question in it's own right

```
$.each(amlData, function (index, item) {
    $('<div class=message><pre><dl><dt>Matched On:</dt><dd>' + item.ItemType +
        '</dd><dt>Date Listed:</dt><dd>' + item.DateListed +
        '</dd><dt>ID:<dt><dd>' + item.ID +
        '</dd><dt>Percentage:</dt><dd>' + item.PercentageMatch +
        '</dd><dt>List:</dt><dd>' + item.List +
        '</dd>' + (item.Gender != null ? '<dt>Gender:</dt><dd>' + item.Gender : '') +
        '</dd>' + (item.Countries.length != 0 ? $.each(item.Countries, function (i, ele) {
        +'<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>' + ele: '')
    }) +
        '</dd></dl></pre></div>').appendTo('div#results');
});
```

Everything above countries, is a single value, however, countries (and other elements) contain multiples.

How do I loop through multiple elements and display their contents inline?

Comment: Add a recursive function for it?

Comment: Daniel, this is intentional - my title stipulates this, plus i mention in the description that this merits it's own question

Comment: why the -1? this is not a duplicate. this question has NOT been answered. ** thanks for correcting **

Comment: @putvande, I shall take a look on the net, for how this could work. Any pointers(sites), which achieve the results i'm after?

Comment: @CSharpNewBee is `item.Countries` just an array of strings?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2Farguments%2Fcallee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you start creating the jquery objects you can do a check and store the string in a variable - using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) will return the values in an array - which you can use [Array.join('')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) afterwards to get it back into string format.

```
var countries = ''; // intialize as empty string
if(item.Countries.length){ // if it has 1 or more
    // map will return this ["<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>USA", "<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>CANADA", "<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>MEXICO"]
    // join makes it this "<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>USA<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>CANADA<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>MEXICO "
    countries = $.map(item.Countries, function (ele) { return '<dt>Countries:</dt><dd>' + ele }).join('');
}
$('<div class=message><pre><dl><dt>Matched On:</dt><dd>test1' +
        '</dd><dt>Date Listed:</dt><dd>test1' +
        '</dd><dt>ID:<dt><dd>test1' +
        '</dd><dt>Percentage:</dt><dd>test1'  +
        '</dd><dt>List:</dt><dd>test1'  +
        '</dd>test1' +
        '</dd>' + countries + // just use variable
        '</dd></dl></pre></div>').appendTo('div#results');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mmght/)

You can move countries into the object creation if you only want one `Countries` heading

```
if(item.Countries.length){
    countries = $.map(item.Countries, function (ele) { return '<dd>' + ele ; }).join('');
}
$('<div class=message><pre><dl><dt>Matched On:<dd>test1' +
        '<dt>Date Listed:<dd>test1' +
        '<dt>ID:<dt><dd>test1' +
        '<dt>Percentage:<dd>test1'  +
        '<dt>List:<dd>test1'  +
        'test1' +
        '<dt>Countries:' + countries +
        '</dl></pre></div>').appendTo('div#results');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6EPLv/)

Comment: is it possible, to only create one Countries heading?

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I updated my answer to only have one heading